# Asynchronously mount function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I need to get some data from an api before rendering my component. I'm trying to use axios (`apiClient`) but it needs an await as it is a promise.

If I set the `setup` function to asynchronous, my template won't render. If I try to set the `data` variable inside an `async/await` block, the template obviously renders before the promise comes back with the response.
How can I get the data from my API and then render my template (already tried it with `OnMounted()`)

```html
<script>
import apiClient from '@/services/axios'
import store from 'store'
import { SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons-vue'
import { defineComponent, reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import {  onMounted } from 'vue'

var data = []; // needs to receive the api response

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    SearchOutlined,
  },
  setup() {    
     response = apiClient.get('/gift/list', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + store.get('token') }})
     data = response.data // set data with api response value
    console.log(data)

    const state =  reactive({
      searchText: '',
      searchedColumn: '',
    })

    const searchInput = ref()

    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Number',
        dataIndex: 'number',
        key: 'number',
        slots: {
          filterDropdown: 'filterDropdown',
          filterIcon: 'filterIcon',
          customRender: 'customRender',
        },
        onFilter: (value, record) =>
          record.number
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
          if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(searchInput.value)
              searchInput.value.focus()
            }, 0)
          }
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'Month',
        dataIndex: 'month',
        key: 'month',
        slots: {
          filterDropdown: 'filterDropdown',
          filterIcon: 'filterIcon',
          customRender: 'customRender',
        },
        onFilter: (value, record) =>
          record.month
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
          if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              searchInput.value.focus()
            })
          }
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'Year',
        dataIndex: 'year',
        key: 'year',
        slots: {
          filterDropdown: 'filterDropdown',
          filterIcon: 'filterIcon',
          customRender: 'customRender',
        },
        onFilter: (value, record) =>
          record.year
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
          if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              searchInput.value.focus()
            })
          }
        },
      },
            {
        title: 'Price',
        dataIndex: 'price',
        key: 'price',
        slots: {
          filterDropdown: 'filterDropdown',
          filterIcon: 'filterIcon',
          customRender: 'customRender',
        },
        onFilter: (value, record) =>
          record.price
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
          if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              searchInput.value.focus()
            })
          }
        },
      },

      {
        title: 'Company',
        dataIndex: 'company',
        key: 'company',
        slots: {
          filterDropdown: 'filterDropdown',
          filterIcon: 'filterIcon',
          customRender: 'customRender',
        },
        onFilter: (value, record) =>
          record.company
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
          if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              searchInput.value.focus()
            })
          }
        },
      },

        {
        title: 'Seller',
        dataIndex: 'addedBy',
        key: 'addedBy',
        slots: {
          filterDropdown: 'filterDropdown',
          filterIcon: 'filterIcon',
          customRender: 'customRender',
        },
        onFilter: (value, record) =>
          record.addedBy
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
          if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              searchInput.value.focus()
            })
          }
        },
      },
    ]

    const handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
      confirm()
      console.log(selectedKeys[0])
      state.searchText = selectedKeys[0]
      state.searchedColumn = dataIndex
    }

    const handleReset = clearFilters => {
      clearFilters()
      state.searchText = ''
    }

    return {
      data,
      columns,
      handleSearch,
      handleReset,
      searchText: '',
      searchInput: null,
      searchedColumn: '',
    }
  },
})
</script>
<style scoped>
.highlight {
  background-color: rgb(255, 192, 105);
  padding: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `ref` that is set asynchronously when the API response is received:

```js
import apiClient from '@/services/axios'
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const myData = ref([])

    onMounted(async () => {
      const response = await apiClient.get(...)
      myData.value = response.data
    })

    return { myData }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fetching-data-on-mount)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way around this would be to add something like `isLoading` to your `data` and set it to `true`.

Then when you get your data back you would set `this.isLoading = false`.

Then simply wrap your component in a `v-if="!isLoading"`.